# How to use AppCompatActivity and RecyclerView and the same time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat

So I've an app that is using RecyclerView but when I click in an image that the recycler contains, I want it to open a DialogFragment. My problem is that when I'm clicking in the image, I need to use 
`getSupportFragmentManager()` but it won't allow me since for that I need to extend my class to AppCompatActivity but I'm already extending it to `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterPerfil.ViewHolder>`.
What can I do? I've already tried to create an different class and make it extend the AppCompatActivity but it didn't work and gave me this error:
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed*.
This is the class which is giving me errors.

```
package com.example.registarmysql;

public class RecyclerViewAdapterPerfil extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterPerfil.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
private String aFotografiaUtilizador;
private String aNomeUtilizador;
private String aEmailUtilizador;
private String aPasswordUtilizador;
private Context aContext;

public RecyclerViewAdapterPerfil(String fotografiaUtilizador, String nomeUtilizador, String emailUtilizador, String passwordUtilizador, Context context) {
    this.aFotografiaUtilizador = nomeUtilizador;
    this.aNomeUtilizador = fotografiaUtilizador;
    this.aEmailUtilizador = emailUtilizador;
    this.aPasswordUtilizador = passwordUtilizador;
    this.aContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");

    Glide.with(aContext).asBitmap().load(aNomeUtilizador).dontTransform().into(holder.fotografiaUtilizador);
    holder.nomeUtilizador.setText(aFotografiaUtilizador);
    holder.emailUtizador.setText(aEmailUtilizador);
    holder.passwordUtilizador.setText(aPasswordUtilizador);

    holder.fotografiaUtilizador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            abrirCaixa();
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on: " + aFotografiaUtilizador);
            Toast.makeText(aContext, "Carregou na foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 1;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CircleImageView fotografiaUtilizador;
    TextView nomeUtilizador;
    TextView emailUtizador;
    TextView passwordUtilizador;
    RelativeLayout parentLayout;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        fotografiaUtilizador = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fotografia_perfil);
        nomeUtilizador = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nome_utilizador);
        emailUtizador = itemView.findViewById(R.id.email_utilizador);
        passwordUtilizador = itemView.findViewById(R.id.password_utilizador);
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    }
}

static class novaClasse extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void abrirCaixaNova(){
        CaixaEditarFotografiaPerfil caixa = new CaixaEditarFotografiaPerfil();
        caixa.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Exemplo de caixa");
    }
}
private void abrirCaixa() {
    new novaClasse().abrirCaixaNova();
}
```

}

the error is in the

```
public void abrirCaixaNova(){
        CaixaEditarFotografiaPerfil caixa = new CaixaEditarFotografiaPerfil();
        caixa.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Exemplo de caixa");
    }
```

Comment: Pass the `FragmentManager` into the constructor of `RecyclerViewAdapterPerfil`.

Comment: yep, it solved the problem, thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the FragmentManager into the constructor of RecyclerViewAdapterPerfil worked.